# If $X$ is a normed vector space and $U\subseteq X$, how do we show $(U^\perp)_\perp=\overline U$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$, $X$ be a normed $\mathbb K$-vector space. It is easy to see that $$U^\perp:=\{\varphi\in X':\langle x,\varphi\rangle=0\text{ for all }x\in U\}$$ is a closed subspace of $X'$ for all $U\subseteq X$ and $$V_\perp:=\{x\in X:\langle x,\varphi\rangle=0\text{ for all }\varphi\in V\}$$ is a closed subspace of $X$ for all $V\subseteq X'$.

> I would like to show

1. If $U\subseteq X$ and $V:=U^\perp$, then $\overline U=V_\perp$.
2. If $V\subseteq X'$ and $U:=V_\perp$, then $\overline V=U^\perp$.

In 1. (resp. 2.) it is easy to show that $U\subseteq V_\perp$ (resp. $V\subseteq U^\perp$) and hence $\overline U\subseteq V_\perp$ (resp. $\overline V\subseteq U^\perp$).

Now I know the proof of the analogue result in the Hilbert space case, but this proof relies on the projection theorem and hence doesn't easily generalize to the present situation.

> So, how do we show $V_\perp\subseteq\overline U$ (resp. $U^\perp\subseteq\overline V$)?

Comment: This is a standard result, in fact, the so-called double annihilator theorem.

Comment: I think 2. should be:  $(V_\bot)^\bot = \overline{V}^{w^*} $, instead of norm closure (in the case of reflexive spaces, the weak-star and norm closure coincide)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that there exist  $ x \in  (U^\bot)_\bot:=  \{ x \in X :  f(x) =0, \text { for all } f \in U^\bot  \}   $ such that    $ x \notin \overline U $. Evidently,  $ x  $ is not zero. From a known Corollary of Hahn-Banach thm, we can find  $ f \in X^* $ such that      $ f(x)=d(x,\overline U)>0  $ and  $ f|_{\overline U}=0 $.
Since   $ f (U) = \{0\} $ we have that   $ f \in U^\bot $. Moreover, since   $ x \in  (U^\bot)_\bot  $, we get that     $ f(x) =0 $ which is impossible.

We now show that $(V_\bot)^\bot := \{ f  \in X^* : f ( V_\bot ) = \{0\}\} = \overline{V}^{w^*} $ (weak-star closure). It is easy to see that  $ \overline {V}^{w^*} \subset (V_\bot)^\bot$. Suppose that there exist  $ x_0^*    \in  (V_\bot)^\bot  \setminus \overline{V}^{w^*} $. From the strong separation thm, we can find  $ x^{**}: (X^*,w^*) \to \mathbb R \ $  linear and continuous such that

$$ \sup_{ v^*  \in \overline{V}^{w^*}} x^{**} (v^*)<x^{**}(x_0^*) . $$

Since  $ x^{**} $ is  $ w^*  $-continuous, we can find $  x\in X$ such that $ x^{**}(x^*)=x^*(x), $ for all  $ x^* \in X^* $. So,

$$ \sup_{v^*  \in \overline{V}^{w^*}} v^*(x)< x^*_0(x) . $$
This leads to a contradiction:

If   $ x\in  V_\bot, $ since  $ \overline {V}^{w^*} \subset  ( V_\bot )^\bot  $, it must be true that     $ 0 = \sup \{ v^*(x) \colon v^*  \in \overline{V}^{w^*} \}< x^*_0(x)=0 $  which is impossible.

If  $ x \notin V_\bot $, then  $ v_0^*(x)\neq 0  \text{ for some  } v_0^*\in V $.  Hence, (since  $\frac{x^*_0(x)}{v_0^*(x)} v_0^*(x) \in \overline {V}^{w^*} $)

$$ \frac{x^*_0(x)}{v_0^*(x)} v_0^*(x)  \leq \sup \{ v^*(x) \colon v^*  \in \overline{V}^{w^*} \}< x^*_0(x)   $$
which is impossible

Answer (score 1):

The proof is greatly facilitated by noting that in general, $M_\perp:=\{x\in X:\langle x,\varphi\rangle=0\text{ for all }\varphi\in M\}$ is norm closed and that $N^\perp:=\{\varphi\in X':\langle x,\varphi\rangle=0\text{ for all }x\in N\}$ is weak$^*$ closed.

For example, Rudin proves the first part like this: by the remark, $\overline V\subseteq (V^{\perp})_{\perp}$. Now, if $x\notin \overline V$ then there is an $x\in V^{\perp}$ such that $\langle x,x^*\rangle \neq 0$ which says that $x\notin (V^{\perp})_{\perp}.$

The second part is similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't $N^\perp$ norm closed as well?

Comment: Yes, but for the second part, to apply the Hahn-Banach theorem, you need $X^*$ to be locally convex, which would not necessarily be true in the norm topolgy. For example, the $L^p$ spaces with $0<p<1.$